# Online RSVP web-app

Tags: gratis, web-apps

I'm about to send out some invitations for an upcoming event. I want to make it easy for them to RSVP (and me to manage), so I'm looking for an online RSVP app.

Requirements:

- free (maximum £10, if I have to pay)
- allows me to set an 'intro' or description visitors will see when they go to the link
- allows me to set custom fields that need to be asked (eg. Name, Comments, +1?, etc...)
- allows me to export data to Excel Spreadsheet (anything else is a bonus)
- looks 'nice' (subjective, but, if you think it looks nice, I'll take it :)
- allows up to 100 visitors (I only have 100 invitations), although any more will be a bonus (for future events)
- non-scary link (eg. http://rsvp.com/shubevent instead of http://snoasfm.com/QYmJNGU?8990hunjn)

Optional Bonuses:

- something to help with seating